# c# - DownloadString with WebClient - 404 Error

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, discord, webclient, downloadstring

I am trying to download string from discord webhook :("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/704770710509453432/GdR4absQHKDKjUiNMpw3aIpX2tx-9Z7nmPE2Sn3TUkQDM12zUczaV-m80orh7WGVzvGK")

When I normally open the site with browser string is : {"message": "Unknown Webhook", "code": 10015}

But when I do that with WebClient:

```
           WebClient wc = new WebClient();
           string site = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/704770710509453432/GdR4absQHKDKjUiNMpw3aIpX2tx-9Z7nmPE2Sn3TUkQDM12zUczaV-m80orh7WGVzvGK";
           string x = wc.DownloadString(site);
```

It gives an "404 Error". Is there a way to get that {"message": "Unknown Webhook", "code": 10015} string with c#?

Comment: The 404 error is that the page is not found.  You are using https (secure) so it may be a SSL/TLS issue.  The best way of finding error is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler. Compare headers in the first request that works with the one that doesn't.  The default headers in c# will be different that webhook.  Modify headers in c# so they look exactly like the working webhool.

Comment: You get a `404` StatusCode even using a WebBrowser. What the WebBrowser does that you're not doing is to read the Response Stream returned by the `[WebException].Response` object. You can read that stream with a StreamReader. You need to use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient in this case. Catch the WebException (it's mandatory anyway) and read the Response object stream with `[StreamReader].ReadToEnd()`. You'll get your json response, exactly how you see it in a WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>A rough guess would be that it's to do with the accept header. Check the documentation for the api, but my browser sent an additional 17 [headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.headers?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_WebClient_Headers) along with the request.</strike>

---

The simple answer would be, use `HttpClient`. It's recommended for new development and also gives the correct response here:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace discordapi_headers
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/704770710509453432/GdR4absQHKDKjUiNMpw3aIpX2tx-9Z7nmPE2Sn3TUkQDM12zUczaV-m80orh7WGVzvGK");
            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

However that doesn't help if you can't. Also I'm intrigued now...

---

**Ha!** I should have listened to my own advice. For web service related stuff, you can't beat fiddler and postman. It turns out that the api is returning a custom 404 to the browser that has json content.

Unfortunately DownloadString sees the 404 and throws a WebException.

Here's an updated version that works, using HttpClient and WebClient.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace discordapi_headers
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string url = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/704770710509453432/GdR4absQHKDKjUiNMpw3aIpX2tx-9Z7nmPE2Sn3TUkQDM12zUczaV-m80orh7WGVzvGK";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await UseHttpClient(url));
            Console.WriteLine(await UseWebClient(url));
        }

        private static async Task<string> UseHttpClient(string url)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        private static async Task<string> UseWebClient(string url)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                return response;
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                using (var s = wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[wex.Response.ContentLength];
                    var contentBytes = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                    return content;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```